# Is it possible to have Visual Studio display a different Solution Explorer name than the csproj file name?

Tags: naming, csproj, fully-qualified-naming

I have a solution with a few projects in them, and each of the projects use a fully qualified name, such as ABC.Appname.Api and ABC.Appname.Web. With a long app name, this can make the names of the projects really long and it is annoying to look for the right one in the solution explorer. It also means I have to have the solution explorer panel wider than I would like.

Is there any way to make the name of the project displayed in the widow different from the name of the csproj file?

I have tried looking at the properties in the csproj file, and there doesn't appear to be anything that effects this. I have to maintain the AssemblyName and I have to continue using fully qualified names for the projects.